# lost network interface to systemd-networkd. What is going on?

Tags: linux-networking, systemd-networkd

I have a systemd host with 4 ethernet ports.

one port is reserved for isolated containers. It is set as:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/20-eth3-reserved.network
[Match]
Name=eth3
[Link]
Unmanaged=yes
```

I also set aliases for the ports, each on its link file, e.g.

```
# /etc/systemd/network/12-alias-eth3.link
[Match]
MACAddress=42:42:42:42:42:03
[Link]
Name=eth3
```

I would later use the unmanaged interface in a systemd-nspawn container with

```
# /etc/systemd/nspawn/container1.nspawn
...
[Network]
Private=yes
VirtualEthernet=no
Interface=eth3
```

At some point (Sept) it was working fine. But a few months ago, the interface with unmanaged setting just vanishes from the system.

nspawn fails to bring up the container saying the interface was not found.

`ip link` shows no eth3, nor the mac address.

`lshw` weirdly shows all managed ports, but DO NOT list the macaddress (`serial` field) for the disabled one.

`dmesg` shows all ports just fine, and list the correct mac address of them all, including disabled one. Later on, it also show the alias being applied!

```
[Wed Nov 10 11:44:31 2021] igb 0000:03:00.3 eth3: renamed from enps0f4
```

So systemd does see the device just fine even after the problem started.

`networkclt` shows all managed ports plus `lo` as `unmanaged`. But no sign of eth3.

I don't mind finding the solution to this if there's a better way to 'reserve' a physical interface to be used with nspawn instead of `Unmanaged=yes`

Answer (score 0):

this would all be too funny if it wasn't a sad highlight of the state systemd still is.

The VM wasn't up, or it was and i was trying to start it up again?, regardless of the case `machinectl list` showed no container up.

The only reason I could find for the interface, which was seen by the kernel, to disappear, was that it was moved to another namespace and that only should happen when nspawn assign the interface to a running container.

But there was no container up, and no way to debug/investigate what happened to it, or to force releases.

And sadly `networkctl` has even less knowledge of namespaces and cgroups than legacy `ps` do.  If the interface is attached somewhere, it is as good as gone.

In the end I could not figure out what was happening, but a system update and reboot resolved the issue for now.